# What is the difference between optimum and robust optimum

Tags: multivariable-calculus, convex-optimization, nonlinear-optimization, stochastic-approximation

While reading some research papers, I come to know that author has explicitly mentioned robust optimum and non-robust optimum terms.
Is there any difference? If yes, can you please explain with an example.

Comment: Robust optimization accounts for the fact that certain parameters appearing in an optimization problem might not be known exactly. Rather, there is a set of possible values for each parameter, or a probability distribution for the parameters. You want to minimize the worst case objective function value,  or the expected objective value. The surprising/interesting thing is that often this can be done by solving a convex problem.

Answer (score 0):

In my experience, an optimum is robust if it is reasonably distant from constraint boundaries.  Yes, optimization tends to drive the design towards a peak, but if there are constraints in the way it will instead tend to drive the design towards 'corners' where different constraints cross.  If you are using optimization to design a physical part of a larger assembly, being up against the constraints is bad: The actual manufacturing process can introduce deviations from the calculated optimum, and if those deviations cross a constraint boundary the part may be unusable.  If the optimum is right up against two or more constraints, a lot of parts could have to be thrown away because of that.  *Robust* optimization, on the other hand, finds a design which, while not theoretically optimum, is close to optimum while being a certain minimum distance from all constraints.  Manufacturing a part according to a robust optimum automatically build in a lot of tolerance, so the manufacturing defect rate can be greatly reduced.  If you have heard the phrase 'Six Sigma', then that's what this is about - reducing defect rates to below one-in-a-million, i.e six 'sigmas' (standard deviations), by careful up-front design.

Of course, the author of that paper might mean something else entirely....

Comment: [link] (http://math.stackexchange.com/a/1974214/365936) I think this robust term is associated with Taguchi Design of Experiment and manufacturing to mean value than LSL and USL. But, I want to know How it is to be understood in the perspective of Multiobjective optimization, where Pareto optimality is considered. Graphs,and visualization could add more value to the response. @PMar